# metrical dashboard set sidebar auto open active by taking current url and checking href using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

https://github.com/swapan730/metrical
this is the dashboard I use

I need to use javascript for the sidebar in this dashboard to check the page urls during page load and set it active automatically, but I'm confused.

my code is as follows

```
  var url = window.location;
  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item a');
  const currentLink = [...allLinks].filter(e => {
    return e.href == url;
  });

  if (currentLink.length > 0) { 
      currentLink[0].classList.add("active");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `if` in `for` for all `<a>`.

```
  for (allLiks){
     if (url == a.href){
       // add class to this a tag
     } 
  }
```

I gave a general answer for someone who is familiar with JavaScript basics.